# Variable Page Table Size

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

I know many people have already asked similar question on this platform, but still I have confusion on this. Please clarify.

If my program needs only 5 page frames initially to store all its things in RAM, it needs only 5 page table entries, right? Or, does it still need 2^20 page table entries?

RAM : 32-bit addressable.
Page Size : 4096 bytes.

Or, Due to stack/heap of a process, it is assumed that a process any time can acquire page frames upto 2^20 ? and increasing/decreasing of page table will become a costly operation. Hence, giving a place to store maximum of 2^20 page frame numbers for each process is a good idea.

Comment: Do you know how page table levels work? You wouldn't start out allocating 2^20 entries, you start out allocating just what you need and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for providing hints to check it further. I will check how page table levels work.